# Can a generic be Nullable?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class RangeFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : IConvertible, IComparable {

  public T Maximum { get; private set; }
  public T Minimum { get; private set; }

  public RangeFilter(T maximum) {
    Minimum = null;
    Maximum = maximum;
  }

}
```

T can be an Int, a Double, ... When I pass only the maximum value I need the Minimum to be null but when I do that I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. 
Consider using 'default(T)' instead.
```

The reason I do not want to use default(T) is because I need to check later if Minimum is defined and default(T) is a valid value for Minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as `T` is not nullable you can not set the value to `null` what you can do is something like this ...

```
public class RangeFilter<T> : IFilter<T> 
    where T : struct, IConvertible, IComparable 
{

    public T? Maximum { get; private set; }
    public T? Minimum { get; private set; }

    public RangeFilter(T maximum) 
    {
        Minimum = null;
        Maximum = maximum;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is where I was headed after I deleted my answer. Given that the usage suggests that `T` appears to be numeric, I think that the `struct` constraint would have been appropriate regardless of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is clearly described by a compiler error, but you can't use `Nullable<T>` because it's completely unusable here (what if `T` is a reference type, or `Nullable<U>`?) Fortunately, you can try an alternative, which is [`Functional.Maybe`](https://github.com/AndreyTsvetkov/Functional.Maybe). It works both for value types and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

The class you are creating is nullable by nature, the type you pass might not be. You can either restrict the type you pass as T ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx))  or change your assignment to support both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could make flags instead of using a magic value to let you know if Minimum was set or not something is set or not

```
public HasMinimum {get; private set;}  

private T _min;
public T Minimum 
{
    get
    {
         if(!HasMinimum)
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Minimum not set");
        return _min;
    }
    private set
    {
       HasMinimum = true;
       _min = value;
    }
}
```

Then in your constructor just don't set the minimum property

```
public RangeFilter(T maximum) 
{
        Maximum = maximum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `double` are not nullable types, so they must have a value assigned to them and that's why you are getting that error. Although, you can use `T?` or `Nullable<T>` as a work around:

```
int? t = null;  // t is nullable, so it works
```

You also can use nested `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault` which can be also useful in your case, if you have a default value for your Min or Max.